# Finding a best palette for a bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, image-processing, bitmap

I am using a format of the bitmap which is based on the palette of N colors:

```
Color[] Palette = {
     color1, color2, color3, ..., colorN
};
```

The bitmaps itself is represented as an array of indexes to the colors from this palette. A Width and Height are specified.

The problem is:
For any fixed N and any standard bitmap determine the best palette.

Comment: The optimum choice of palette depends on the contents of the bitmap.

Comment: Anyway, there should be several approaches. And I would be glad to find out about them. And then to choose among them.

Comment: In what format do you have your colors?

Comment: System.Drawing.Color which I convert to UInt32 (ARGB). Actually, Alpha component is not used.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization describes (very briefly, but with pointers to more detail) a number of algorithms you can use for this. If that isn't sufficient, you might want to make your question more specific.

Comment: I wasn't aware that anyone still used palettes in new code!

Comment: It is used in GUI library for embedded development.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without you describing how you plan to deal with colors that don't fit the palette.  Frankly, this is a problem that dates from the previous century.  Or a homework assignment.  Not having to deal with palettes anymore is a great joy, it is *progress*.

Comment: I am finding the closest match for any color that is not present in the palette. In fact, I was impressed than having not too big pallete, the actual colorful picture can be encoded with a small result size. This can be relevant for embedded system with bounded resources. No, it is not a home assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay for Google.

http://www.adrianhopgood.com/pub/IEEE-SMC2006.pdf

http://itee.uq.edu.au/~aprs/dicta2003/pdf/0781.pdf

http://www.leptonica.com/papers/colorquant.pdf